# How to concisely define a typescript type with n keys that are all the same type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

For some scientific calculations, I have an object of input parameters, that are all number types. Typing all out manually looks like this:

```js
type parameters = {gdp: number, interest: number, inflation: number, ...}
```

Is there any way to do the same using an array of keys that are all assigned the same number type?
Something in principle like this perhaps:

```
type parameteres = {(...[gdp, interest, inflation]): number}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Normally I would post `type CustomType = { [T in 'foo' | 'bar' | 'qux'] : number };` as an answer but not sure of how much you are attached to *array of keys*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing [Wiktor's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69153250/how-to-concisely-define-a-typescript-type-with-n-keys-that-are-all-the-same-type#comment122223249_69153250), here are some different ways you can define the type, keeping it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUDaBpKBLAdlA5AOYAmY+UAPgbsBAE4QDOw5V+uAZgDYCGwWAexz4AugC4oOAK4BbAEb0oAXwDcAWABQoSFABCCKACUIAYwF1iAHiKlW1HLQbM77HNz6DhAGkmyFdAD51DU0AelDsDigQASkoAHceBygeExMmRihgASyAC2gAawgQTJ5SqCkcTygILkYIePyGTW1oAEkcMClgdGKAYQARAxsySntHJhYx13d+IXxg1qg+gxQMbDwOrp7+gfFfeUVVFvBoIcRjMwtLLe7ekEGfaUPA4LCIrCiYuJwICGI8oViqVMnRKvwZNBiHweD5sgJNGYcMwNtt7plEKgRvgfK4Js5cZxeHNhCIUpkkcxFqcoLcdiAAKIAMQMrQEUVwaOBqGe-hE1J0DNWaEwuFpnTuxWZ+15RwF0BZF1M5isdPuzKefnoQU0Jx0dIACjw6DwZBjYGN9FQVlQhlQhVQmcFiKZeAwoJTgKjuhJDcbTYxgpzugA6EhgKDhA7+TTB4Ahmj0SZR2V0WMS+NEjxCFNatMaOMhngAN3oPEI0Cj9Do5k0QA)

```ts
type A = { [K in 'gdp' | 'interest' | 'inflation']: number };
type B = Record<'gdp' | 'interest' | 'inflation', number>;

// if you want access to the keys as a union elsewhere
type InputKeyCD = 'gdp' | 'interest' | 'inflation';
type C = { [K in InputKeyCD]: number };
type D = Record<InputKeyCD, number>;

// if you need the keys as runtime data, too
const inputKeys = ['gdp', 'interest', 'inflation'] as const;
type InputKeyEF = typeof inputKeys[number];
type E = { [K in InputKeyEF]: number };
type F = Record<InputKeyEF, number>;

type InputParams = A | B | C | D | E | F;
declare const input: InputParams;
input.gdp // number
input.interest// number
input.inflation// number
input.average // error
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Wasn't aware of the Record type